# iOS - progressbar with value from php

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a progress bar in my app showing a percent value.

```
progressView = [[DDProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 140.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width - 40.0f, 0.0f)];
[progressView setOuterColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[progressView setInnerColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[self.view addSubview:progressView];
[progressView release];
float randomPercentageFloat = 40;
progressView.progress = randomPercentageFloat / 100;
```

This shows a progress bar which is 40% full. I want to make the progress bar to show a value from a php. I have a php file that echoes a value. I want to change the `randomPercentageFloat = 40;` to something like

```
float randomPercentageFloat = "www.website.com/value.php";
```

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Comment: "I have a progress bar in Xcode" - rather in your app, right? This doesn't have anything to do with Xcode.

Comment: Its in my app yes. I edited the post so you can see the whole code now

Comment: You'll need to create an NSURLConnection to create a request to your PHP to get the value that will be used in your progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

You have to establish connection with your server e retrieve the value, following the sample cose

test.php contains this instruction:

```
<?php echo 40; ?>
```

here sample viewController.m with progress view linked via Interface Builder

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;

    NSMutableData *receivedData;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    progressView.progress = 0.0f;

    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.29/test.php"]
                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                 timeoutInterval:10.0];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (!theConnection) {
        UIAlertView *connectFailMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NSURLConnection " message:@"Failed in viewDidLoad"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [connectFailMessage show];
    } 

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{


    // inform the user
    UIAlertView *didFailWithErrorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"NSURLConnection " message: @"didFailWithError"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [didFailWithErrorMessage show];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: receivedData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    progressView.progress = [dataString floatValue] / 100;
}


@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! umm.. When I use this code I can build the project with no errors but it crashes when the bar pops up. The problem seems to be in the `[recievedData appendData:data];` Where it says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, adress=0xe0741af7)" I have no idea what this means

Comment: Did you defined recievedData in h files? Did you allocated recievedData? I tried this code in Xcode and it works fine. Check your code better